My function for read_BMP_header don`t work on valid width ana height check
Here is text of check: "Given the valid BMP stream When the function is invoked Then the image width must be valid And the image height must be valid"
Here is file bmp.h
#ifndef _BMP_H
#define _BMP_H

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


#define PADDING_CHAR "\0"

/**
 * Structure contains information about the type, size, layout, dimensions
 * and color format of a BMP file. Size of structure is 54 bytes.
*/
struct bmp_header{
    uint16_t type;              // "BM" (0x42, 0x4D)
    uint32_t size;              // file size
    uint16_t reserved1;         // not used (0)
    uint16_t reserved2;         // not used (0)
    uint32_t offset;            // offset to image data (54B)
    uint32_t dib_size;          // DIB header size (40B)
    uint32_t width;             // width in pixels
    uint32_t height;            // height in pixels
    uint16_t planes;            // 1
    uint16_t bpp;               // bits per pixel (1/4/8/24)
    uint32_t compression;       // compression type (0/1/2) 0
    uint32_t image_size;        // size of picture in bytes, 0
    uint32_t x_ppm;             // X Pixels per meter (0)
    uint32_t y_ppm;             // X Pixels per meter (0)
    uint32_t num_colors;        // number of colors (0)
    uint32_t important_colors;  // important colors (0)
} __attribute__((__packed__));


/**
 * Reads BMP header from input stream
 *
 * Reads and returns BMP header from opened input stream. The header is located
 * at it's beginning. If the stream is not opened or it is corrupted, function
 * returns `NULL`.
 *
 * @param stream opened stream, where the image data are located
 * @return `bmp_header` structure or `NULL`, if stream is not open or broken
 */
struct bmp_header* read_bmp_header(FILE* stream);

here is my fuction read_bmp_header:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "bmp.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct bmp_header* read_bmp_header(FILE* stream){
    //проверка на успешное открытие файла
        if(stream == NULL) return NULL;
    

    //создание структуры для хранения заголовка БМП
    struct bmp_header* header = (struct bmp_header*)malloc(sizeof(struct bmp_header));
    if(header == NULL) return NULL;

    //проверка на чтение даных заголовка файла
    size_t succes_read = fread(header, sizeof(struct bmp_header), 1, stream);
    
    if(succes_read != 1){
        free(header);
        return NULL;
    }
    
    if(header->type != 0x4D42 || header->width == 0 || header->height == 0 || header->offset != 54 || header->dib_size != 40 || header->bpp != 24 || header->image_size == 0){
        free(header);
        return NULL;
    }

    if(header->width > UINT32_MAX || header->height > UINT32_MAX){
        free(header);
        return NULL;
    }

    return header;
}

Here is what bot, which dp checks, print after check:
Given the valid BMP stream When the function is invoked Then the image width must be valid And the image height must be valid
STDOUT: Running suite(s): read_bmp_header()
Reasons of failure:
Segmentation fault
Return code of executed application is different than expected.
Now i don`t know what i need to do. please help me if you know.

How can a uint32_t width or height member be > UINT32_MAX? Note that the height may be negative to indicate top to bottom storage. The height should be a signed integer.

@WeatherVane i can`t edit bmp.h file

OK so you've read the header and checked certain fields. I don't get what the problem is.

@WeatherVane I also don't get what the problem is. I push my code to Arene (it do checks), and had the problem, which i describe above

How do expect anyone to reproduce that with only a single function posted?

@WeatherVane I can post other functions if need.

Welcome, please post a Minimal Reproducible Example, the shortest complete code that shows the problem.

@WeatherVane The problem is also that I don't know what data is passed to the function during the check. above I wrote everything he knows about the check.

header->width > UINT32_MAX This check is pointless. A uint32_t variable cannot hold any value greater than UINT32_MAX.
